# "Leave something for later" vs. "leave something for later on"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning betweeb *leave something for later* and *leave something for later on*? For example:

> When you run the distance, don't go all out right away. **Leave some energy for later**.
>
> When you run the distance, don't go all out right away. **Leave some energy for later on**.

Comment: I guess the second one's grammatically incorrect.

Comment: The second one is (also) natural in British English. Both have the same meaning as far as I can see.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that 'on' was unnecessary though that's not grammatically incorrect.

Comment: *On* just stresses continuation over time, promotes an idea of *further*. I think both are grammatically correct and can be used in your example... Later on might be even more appropriate because we are talking about you will keep running after your energy is at a low level.

Comment: I doubt the word choice here. Conserve/save/don't waste would work better for me...

Comment: _Later on_ is a perfectly standard expression meaning _at a time in the (near) future_, even though it could be argued that the _on_ is unnecessary.